# Display custom field content in node.tpl

Tags: entities, theming, files

i've a custom filefield in a custom content type and i use to display it in a node.tpl .But here my filefield has no limit number and under D6 i use this code :

```
    foreach($node->field_objectif_bts as $file) {
  if ($file['view']) {
      $header = array('data' => 'Les objectifs des formations BTS');
      $rows[] = array($file['view']);
      $attributes = array('id'=> 'objectif-bts','sticky' => FALSE);
    }
}

$output = theme('table', $header,$rows, $attributes);
print $output;
```

In Drupal 7 it doesn't work, so I'm looking for modifications to do on this code or new code for Drupal 7 theming.

Actually, I tried the following.

```
foreach($node->field_objectif_bts as $file) {
  if ($file['und']['value']) {
      $header = array('data' => 'Les objectifs des formations BTS');
      $rows = array($file['und'][0]['value']);
      $attributes = array('id'=> 'objectif-bts','sticky' => FALSE);
    }
}

$output = theme('table', array('header' => $header, 'rows'=> $rows), $attributes);
print $output;
```

I also tried this code, but I get an error.

```
$w = entity_metadata_wrapper('node', $node);
foreach ($w->field_objectif_bts->getIterator() as $file_w) {
  // $file_w->file returns the wrapper of the File entity. You can
  // then address it's values as:
  $name = $file_w->file->name->value();
  $mime = $file_w->file->mime->value();
  $custom_field = $file_w->file->field_objectif_bts->value();
  // etc. You can see all available fields by inspecting the
  // return value of $file_w->file->getPropertyInfo()
  if ($custom_field) {
      $header = array('data' => 'Les objectifs des formations BTS');
      $rows = array($custom_field);
      $attributes = array('id'=> 'objectif-bts','sticky' => FALSE);
    }
    $output = theme('table', array('header' => $header, 'rows'=> $rows), $attributes);
print $output;
}
```

The error is the following:

> EntityMetadataWrapperException: Unknown data property field_objectif_bts. in EntityStructureWrapper->getPropertyInfo() (line 339 of /var/www/drupal7/sites/all/modules/entity/includes/entity.wrapper.inc).

Answer (score 2):

There are two parts in your problem: one is getting the values, and the second is themeing them.

As far as getting the values is concerned, if you don't mind using the [Entity](http://drupal.org/project/entity) and [File Entity](http://drupal.org/project/file_entity) modules, a simpler way to access field content is to use [entity metadata wrappers](http://drupal.org/node/1021556). This way you don't need to worry about deltas and languages.

You can write code as follows:

```
$w = entity_metadata_wrapper('node', $node);
foreach ($w->field_objectif_bts->getIterator() as $file_w) {
  // $file_w->file returns the wrapper of the File entity. You can
  // then address it's values as:
  $name = $file_w->file->name->value();
  $mime = $file_w->file->mime->value();
  $custom_field = $file_w->file->field_custom_field->value();
  // etc. You can see all available fields by inspecting the
  // return value of $file_w->file->getPropertyInfo()
}
```

As far as themeing the table goes, I think your call to theme is correct (If unsure, you can check the documentation for [theme_table](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!theme.inc/function/theme_table/7))

Comment: it's very different as D6..so i learn about this actually and your links are useful.
i am not sure about your code, is it only for theming ? or is it for getting value and theming a field ?

Comment: D7 uses Entities, which is a new concept not present in D6. Your code was accessing field values on the "$node" object. I'm providing an alternative D7 way of doing this, which I consider cleaner than directly using the values on the $node object - however you can still do that in D7 if you wish.

Comment: (So the code I provided is only for accessing values on a node object. You can use/theme those as you wish)

Comment: i think i do add the file_entity module too ?

Comment: Ah yes you're right - I have the File Entity module enabled too, sorry I forgot about it. I've edited the answer to add that into it.

Comment: your code take errors i think : `Warning: array_flip(): Can only flip STRING and INTEGER values! in DrupalDefaultEntityController->load() (line 178 of /var/www/drupal7/includes/entity.inc).` not ?

Comment: i find about field_view_field function that seem can do the trick..if someone has done this yet and can explain to me..thanks